# after php mail has been sent, ajax responds with an error message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I am trying to show a status massage after sending a mail via AJAX.
The mail is sending without a problem, but instead of showing the success message, it displays the error one.
In my eyes the json data should be valid.
Maybe you can help me, with regards philman.

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send_btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: $('#contact').attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#contact').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#send_btn').html('sendet...');
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response) {  
                    if(response['signal'] == 'ok') {
                        $('#msg').html('<div class="alert_success">' + response['msg'] + '</div>');
                        $('input, textarea').val(function() {
                            return this.defaultValue;
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#msg').html('<div class="alert_warning">' + response['msg'] + '</div>');
                    }
                } 
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#msg').html('<div class="alert_warning">Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.</div>');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#send_btn').html('Abschicken');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

RequestHandler - sending mail with SMTP:

```
<?php

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';

//Empfänger E-Mail
$recipient = 'recipient';

//Formularfelder
$vname = trim($_POST['vname']);
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

if($name != null && $email != null && $message != null) {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);      

        //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();    
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                   
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.1und1.de';          
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
        $mail->Username = 'username';   
        $mail->Password = 'passowrd';    
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
        $mail->Port = 25;                                         

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom("$recipient", 'recipient');
        $mail->addAddress("$recipient", 'recipient');     
        $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

        $body = "<p><strong>Name: </strong>$vname $name <br> <strong>Nachricht: </strong>$message</p>";

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);            
        $mail->Subject = 'Kontaktformular';
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

        if(!$mail->send()){
            $signal = 'bad';
            $msg = 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $signal = 'ok';
            $msg = 'Nachricht versendet, vielen Dank!';
        }

    } else {
        $signal = 'bad';
        $msg = 'Ungültige E-Mail-Adresse, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.';
    }
} else {
    $signal = 'bad';
    $msg = 'Bitte füllen Sie alle erforderlichen Felder aus.';
}

$data = array(
    'signal' => $signal,
    'msg' =>  $msg
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

Comment: When you debug the call in a browser, what response code do you get back from your PHP? And what's in your web server error log? (The first thing I see in your PHP file is you `use`ing PHPMailer before bringing in its autoloader—are you sure your PHP function works at all? If it were throwing a server error that would explain what you're seeing. Tools like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) can be handy for getting the PHP working before you write the jQuery...)

Comment: You have not specify if it display error message in success function or in error function.

Comment: The console doesn't show any errors or what do you exactly mean?

Comment: What exact error do you get, is it the one from the else block for `if($mail->send())`  It's a stupid question, but I have to ask it as you didnt put the exact error message you get.  Personally I would change this line to `if(response['signal'] == 'ok') {` to this `if(response.signal && response.signal == 'ok') {` but it's nit picking and probably not your issue.  It will avoid an error if `response.signal` is undefined though...

Comment: Oh okay, it's showing the div from the error function - error: function() {
                        $('#msg').html('<div class="alert_warning">Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.</div>');
                    }

Comment: @philman  you can put backtics around code in the comments inline ` its the same key as the tilde ~  Makes it way nicer to read.

Comment: Alright, my bad. I will have a look at it, thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @philman - that's the error function in the Ajax request right?  That means something iin the back-end script is failing, you should inspect the network request using the browser debugging window ( usually `F12` ) and then most of them have a network panel.  It could be something simple like a `404 not found error`  lol @ `Abschicken` not sure what language that is but i see `Abs chicken` ha ha

Comment: The debugging window show's me this warning: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
And its german :D

Comment: Just wanted to tell you that i fixed it by using another host and changing port to 25 instead of 587.